# change background color of edittext in fragment using color picker

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, color-picker

I want to change the background color of my edit text using color picker. I have got a class and in it there is an editText. I am using fragment and in the fragment that particular editText of that class is being used. In the fragment there is an image view clicking on which the color picker dialog is shown.

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
   EditText et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTest);

   ImageView imgChooser = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgPallete);

}

public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    imgChooser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AmbilWarnaDialog colorpicker = new AmbilWarnaDialog(getContext(), Color.BLACK, new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {
                    et.setBackgroundColor(color);
                }
            });
            colorpicker.show();
        }
    });

}
```

but this is not working and shows  java.lang.NullPointerException. Can anybody please help me? I am new to android studio.

The error log is as follow

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                                 at com.example.sudeepbajracharya.myapplication.BackGround$1$1.onOk(BackGround.java:61)
                                                                                                 at yuku.ambilwarna.AmbilWarnaDialog$6.onClick(AmbilWarnaDialog.java:179)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:169)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the problem is being showed in line 61 and In line BackGround.java:61 there is
       et.setBackgroundColor(color);

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException` share your whole crash log with question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Nilu I have shared my crash log.  Please look at it. :) Thank You

Comment: Share full activity code please with XML.

Comment: Can you Toast what this color value in onOk .   `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), color, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Your et variable which you initialized is local to onViewCreated. As you have not provided whole code, i assume the et variable declared globally is not initialized and due to that is giving you NPE.

Comment: @Sudeep, i hope your problems has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

your `EditText` not reference properly so try below code

```
private EditText et;
private ImageView imgChooser;

public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
   et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTest);

   imgChooser = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgPallete);

}

public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    imgChooser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AmbilWarnaDialog colorpicker = new AmbilWarnaDialog(getContext(), Color.BLACK, new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {
                    et.setBackgroundColor(color);
                }
            });
            colorpicker.show();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: thank you for your response brother but it still does not work :( i am having problem in et.setBackgroundColor(color);

Answer (score 0):

**You can use**

```
edittext.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
```

or if above code snipt not work then you can try below code

If you are in activity use this

```
edittext.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.yourcolor));
```

if you are in fragment use below code

```
edittext.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(),R.color.yourcolor));
```

if you are in recyclerview adapter use below code

```
edittext.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.yourcolor));
```

Because, `edittext.setBackgroundColor()` takes a **color in numeric** form (e.g., 0xFFFF0000 for red). R.color.white is also a number.

**and make sure you have correct reference of `edittext`**